# How to pass the session value declared in the Controller to jquery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have created a function in controller in which I have created three sessions and passed the values. I need to pass the values to some variables in jquery file to use it in a function.
Here is the controller function

```
public string GetAssociatedCompSetsForGroup(string groupID, string ScreenName)
    {
        Session["WorkBookID"] = Session["workbookId"];
        Session["groupID"] =  groupID;
        Session["ScreenName"] = ScreenName;
        IList<int> compSetsIds = serviceKMALocator.InvokeService<IList<int>>(x => x.GetAssociatedCompSetsForGroup(Convert.ToInt32(groupID), ScreenName));
        string ids = string.Empty;
        foreach (int id in compSetsIds)
        {
            ids = ids + id.ToString() + Constant.SemiColon;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
        {
            ids = ids.Substring(0, ids.Length - 1);
        }
        ViewBag.CompSetIds = ids;
        Session[Constant.CompSetIds] = compSetsIds;
        return ids;
    }
```

and the values of three sessions i have created in the controller should be passed to the variables in the following code and i have tried something like this.

```
 var GroupID = '<%=Session("groupID")%>';
var WorkBookID = '<%=Session("WorkBookID")%>';
var ScreenName = '<%=Session("ScreenName")>';


if (GroupID != null && WorkBookID != null && ScreenName != null) 
{


    $.post(compsetForGroup, { groupID: GroupID, ScreenName: ScreenName }, function (jsonData) {
        if (jsonData) {
            function ajaxCall(no) { .....
```

Please help me with the correct format. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: I don't think `null` has any meaning in JavaScript, it's a C# thing and if your session variable is `null` your JavaScript variable will just be an empty string (`''`). Replace `!= null` with `!= ''`. BTW in your last variable you're missing a `%` too.

Comment: Is ASP handling and parsing the output of the JS file before it is sent to the browser? If not then you will need to use AJAX to request the necessary variables from your session.

Comment: No the value itself is not getting passed to the variables I could find the format '<%=Session("groupID")%>'; wrong but i dont know what is the correct format please help me out

Comment: I need to pass the value of the session [ Session["groupID"] =  groupID;] in controller to a variable [ var GroupID ] in jquery.  I am very poor in jquery and mvc. Please suggest me the steps to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Well `<%=Session("groupID")%>` seems to be correct syntax for printing an ASP variable but if ASP is not parsing this JS file then if you view the source code in the browser you should literally see `var GroupID = '<%=Session("groupID")%>';`. I'll make a post outlining the fundamental concept of AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

in your JavaScript Codes:

```
var WorkBookID = "@Session[0]";
var groupID= "@Session[1]";
var ScreenName = "@Session[2]";
```

that sessions 0 to 2 is equivalence to the value of WorkBookID ,groupID,ScreenName  sessions Respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var GroupID = '<%=Session["groupID"]%>';
var WorkBookID = '<%=Session["WorkBookID"]%>';
var ScreenName = '<%=Session["ScreenName"]>';


if (GroupID && WorkBookID && ScreenName) 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it

```
 var OppoId = '@(OMSSession.SessionProperties.SelectedOpportunityId)';
```